# Extract 'WeekDay Month Date HH:MM:SS' from Filename?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have files which contain the full date and time in its name. I want to extract the particular format and print that as my first line of CSV I am writing.

My file name is like below:

```
VIN5_2019-04-03_10-21-26_38
```

I want the first line of my CSV to print as below:

```
date Wed Apr 3 10:21:26.000 am 2019
```

My code is below:

```
import can
import csv
import datetime
import re

filename = open('C:\\Users\\xyz\\files\\time_linear_Hexa.csv', "w")
log1 = can.BLFReader('C:\\Users\\xyz\\blf files\\VIN5_2019-04-03_10-33-59_39.blf')
filename.write(re.search("([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})", filename))
filename.write('base hex  timestamps absolute\ninternal events logged \n// version 11.0.0 \n')
```

How can I achieve date and time in the same format as the file image like shown in the screenshot below?

[image: screenshot of desired file contents]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookahead and loosbehind to extract the datetime string, use `strptime` to convert it to a datetime object and then use `strftime` to formate it to the desired form.

```
import re
import datetime from datetime
s = "VIN5_2019-04-03_10-21-26_38"

res = re.search('(?<=\w{5})[\w-]*(?=_\d{2})', s)
dt_string = res[0]

dt = datetime.strptime(dt_string, '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')

'{} {} {}'.format(dt.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3], dt.strftime('%p').lower(), dt.strftime('%Y'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regex and [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module.

**Ex:**

```
import re
import datetime
s = "VIN5_2019-04-03_10-21-26_38"
m = re.search(r"[A-Z]+\d_(?P<date>\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})_(?P<time>\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})", s)
if m:
    print(datetime.datetime.strptime("{} {}".format(m.group('date'), m.group('time')), "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S").strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%f %p %Y"))
```

**Output:**

```
Wed Apr 03 10:21:26.000000 AM 2019
```